# Find Linear Transformation Given Set of Vertex

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A parallelogram P in the $xy$-plane has vertex $(0,0)$, $(2, 10)$, $(3, 17)$, and 
$(1, 7)$.

I need to find a linear transformation that maps P onto a rectangle $R$ in the $uv$-plane with opposite vertices $(0,0)$ and $(4,2)$ in order to calculate a related integral.

I can't seem to find a correct linear transformation. What could I try? Is there a procedure that can be applied in this sort of scenarios?

Comment: I did what user2566092 and gt6989b suggested, and got that ($u,v$) = ($7x-y$, $-5x+y$).

I wasn't properly using the fact that both vertex had to be opposite to each other. In this case it worked, but could it happen that the linear transformation rotates them?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since you have common vertices $(0,0)$, it all boils down to transforming the side vectors extending from $(0,0)$ from one quadrilateral to the other. This can easily be done with elementary matrix operation construction. Let me know if you'd like me to spell it out more fully and I'll be happy to do so.

Comment: I've got it. Could it be possible, in some other case, that the transformation also rotates those vectors into different axis?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
You need to map $(2,10)$ to $(0,4)$ and $(1,7)$ into $(0,2)$. What does this say about the transformation matrix $A$?

**UPD** In other words,
$$A \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix},$$

can you take it from here?

Comment: It's funny, we both said exactly the same thing but just in different ways and focusing on different details. I guess with "hints" it's all a matter of taste. =)

Comment: @user2566092 indeed, you are geometric and i am algbraic :) -- i guess it more of a question of how far to spell things out. I am happy to see others hint as well without giving away the result so the OP doesn't do any work at all...

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your linear transformation is a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ that satisfies
\begin{align*}
A\begin{bmatrix}2\\10\end{bmatrix} 
&= \begin{bmatrix}4\\0\end{bmatrix} &
A\begin{bmatrix}1\\7\end{bmatrix}
&= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} &
A\begin{bmatrix}3\\17\end{bmatrix}
&= \begin{bmatrix}4\\2\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Note, however, that the third equation is redundant since the first two equations imply
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}3\\17\end{bmatrix}
= A\left(
\begin{bmatrix}2\\10\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}1\\7\end{bmatrix}
\right)
=A\begin{bmatrix}2\\10\end{bmatrix}+
A\begin{bmatrix}1\\7\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}4\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}4\\2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus we need only find a $2\times 2$ matrix satisfying
\begin{align*}
A\begin{bmatrix}2\\10\end{bmatrix} 
&= \begin{bmatrix}4\\0\end{bmatrix} &
A\begin{bmatrix}1\\7\end{bmatrix}
&= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
But this is equivalent to finding a $2\times 2$ matrix satisfying
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\10&7\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$
If we multiply both sides of this equation on the right by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\10&7\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
we obtain
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\10&7\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
Can you invert the matrix and carry out the multiplication to find $A$?

Of course, once we have our matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a& b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}
$$
our answer is
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ax+by\\ cx+dy\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I will definitely keep that one in mind. I am currently doing this in a calculus course (the objective of the transformation is to then help solve an integral), so I didn't consider the matrix route, but it's simple enough. Thanks a lot, Brian.